# What is unsafe reflection in Java?

Tags: java, reflection

I've been unable to find an explanation of "unsafe reflection" in Java.  I came across it in a [blog post](https://proandroiddev.com/most-elegant-way-of-using-gson-kotlin-with-default-values-and-null-safety-b6216ac5328c) that mentions that GSON uses unsafe reflection, but offers no further details.  I know what reflection is.  But what's "unsafe" reflection?

Comment: See [this](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Unsafe_use_of_Reflection) and [this](https://www.baeldung.com/java-unsafe) for possible meanings of "unsafe" reflection. I'm thinking it would be the latter, though.

Comment: Possibly it's this post: [GSON Unsafe Problem](https://medium.com/@programmerr47/gson-unsafe-problem-d1ff29d4696f)

Comment: @MickMnemonic It was a different post.  But the one you mentioned might be relevant and helpful.

Comment: I guess this [Unsafe Reflection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Unsafe_use_of_Reflection#targetText=This%20vulnerability%20is%20caused%20by,limited%20form%20of%20code%20injection.) can help you to understand

Answer (score 1):

After more research and help from the links provided by other users in the comments to the original post, I'm thinking "unsafe reflection" means allocating (i.e. instantiating) a class without using any of its constructors.  This is done by reflection.  What may be meant by "unsafe" is that an instance is considered safe to use, or in a safe state (of construction), only after constructors have completely executed.  Not coincidentally, the class used to accomplish this feat is `sun.misc.Unsafe`.

Answer (score 0):

Using the phrase "unsafe reflection", in general, is a little like using the phrase "dangerous explosion"--the adjective is almost redundant, but we still sometimes use it.

Reflection bypasses the type-checking that the compiler does.  For instance, you can create a new instance of a `Class<String>` by doing something like (I haven't checked this)

```
Class<String> theStringClass = (Class<String>) Class.forName("java.lang.String")`
```

but this is somewhat unsafe because if you made a mistake and had

```
Class<String> myStringClass = (Class<String>) Class.forName("java.lang.Sting")`
```

or

```
Class<String> myStringClass = (Class<String>) Class.forName("java.lang.Integer")`
```

you won't get an error until the line of code actually gets run.  In contrast, if you do something like

```
Class<String> myStringClass = Sting.class
```

the compiler will give you an error right away.  So as a *general* rule, reflection is unsafe.

In the blog-post, the "unsafe-ness" might be due to GSON doing something like Article.class.newInstance() instead of directly calling the constructor (and setting default values), but it's not immediately clear to me.